# How to write function that reads a json file into a list of objects

Tags: python, json

I am new to python, so I may be misunderstanding the directions that I have been given.

I was told to "*Create a class for a registrant called Registrant. It should derive from class dict and have keys that match the fields in the JSON data file*". So I wrote this.

```
class Registrant(dict):
    _keys = ['email', 'exp_year', 'card_number', 'state', 'zipcode', 'card_type', 'billing_lastname',
             'title', 'meals', 'company', 'lastname', 'exp_month', 'firstname', 'session3', 'session1',
             'position', 'date_of_registration', 'telephone', 'address1', 'card_csv', 'address2', 'city',
             'website', 'session2', 'billing_firstname']
```

The next instructions and where I am confused are:
"*Write a function called getJSONdata that reads the registrant_data.json file into a list of Registrant objects*". So I wrote this:

```
def getJSONdata():
  import json
  jsonRegistrants = []
  with open('registrant_data.json', 'r') as json_file:
      dataObject = json.load(json_file)

      for registrants in dataObject['registrants']:
          jsonRegistrants.append(registrants)

          print(jsonRegistrants)
```

In the directions though it says to create a list of "Registrant object" and I assume this should be a method instead?

I am not able to clear this up with the instructor, so I am asking the pros instead.

[Project Directions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgv71o2zj1b4ut0/Assignment8.pdf?dl=0)

[Example of JSON data](http://pastebin.com/4ZVWFPe5)

Comment: Can you show the input data? Your attempt looks ok but you could save the loop and just say `jsonRegistrants = dataObject['registrants']`.

Comment: It comes out, but (dumb question) is that technically a "list of registrants"?

Comment: No I suppose not. Its a list of dicts I assume. I'm not sure about the finer details of your assignment, but to achieve this you could just do `jsonRegistrants.append(Registrant(registrants))` and technically it would then be a Registrant. it seems fairly pointless and I'm not certain what that teaches you.

Comment: Its for a website we've been making. I'm not much of a coder, but we have jumped from 2 other languages in one class and it has been throwing me off. Anyways, [here is a pdf for more context](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgv71o2zj1b4ut0/Assignment8.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Not sure why the assignment says to _derive_ class `Registrant` from `dict` when it could just be an _instance_ of a regular one with the proper keys added to it. Deriving a subclass just to give it predefined values doesn't make much sense. Even if it did, I don't think you're supposed to hardcode them like that. To avoid that, you need to read JSON data (which isn't in the pdf). Including an example of it in your question would also help.